# Debugger in Visual Studio Code with JavaScript is not working. Code 134

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

So, I have an error that occurs when i want to debug a program with JavaScript on Visual Studio         Code. I made a launch.json file and when i click the green triangle for start the debugging starts and immediately stops.
The output in the debug console is:

"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" ".\05. Account Balance.js"
Process exited with code 134

How can i fix this error, i've tried everyting

I uninstalled Node.js and Visual Studio Code 3 times. But still nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.